# Why is GoogleBot interested in [index.php] when my root redirects to [/en/home]?

Tags: redirect, indexing, http-status-code-404, googlebot, directoryindex

for the past months, googleBot has been hitting a file that does not exist anymore on my site [index.php] as all the routing to the proper home pages in the proper  languages is handled via apache rewrite rules in the htaccess.

Ans to, I commented out my .htaccess the `DirectoryIndex index.php`  rule

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
Options +FollowSymLinks -Indexes -ExecCGI
# DirectoryIndex index.php    (not needed anymore, index.php doesnt exist)
# DirectoryIndex /en/home     (should it be set to this now??)
```

Currently, Everything works sublime: the `http://website.org` root is redirected instantly to `/en/home` via 301 permanent rediret!

## *But*

66.249.67.142 / ==  crawl-66-249-67-142.googlebot.com  is hitting my site again and again trying to read index.php, which does not exist. What should I do??

A sneak peak into the endless error log file with such entries (poor googlebot i thought it might be more intelligent...)

```
[Fri Mar 04 20:48:30 2011] [error] [client 66.249.66.177] File does not exist: 
/var/www/vhosts/site.com/httpdocs/index.php

[Fri Mar 04 20:58:59 2011] [error] [client 66.249.66.177] File does not exist: 
/var/www/vhosts/site.com/httpdocs/index.php

[Fri Mar 04 21:00:18 2011] [error] [client 66.249.67.142] File does not exist: 
/var/www/vhosts/site.com/httpdocs/index.php

[Fri Mar 04 21:01:05 2011] [error] [client 66.249.66.177] File does not exist: 
/var/www/vhosts/site.com/httpdocs/index.php

[Fri Mar 04 21:12:28 2011] [error] [client 66.249.66.164] File does not exist: 
/var/www/vhosts/site.com/httpdocs/index.php

[Fri Mar 04 21:27:30 2011] [error] [client 66.249.68.115] File does not exist: 
/var/www/vhosts/site.com/httpdocs/index.php
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Someone linked to index.php, so Google is trying to follow it.

Do a rewrite from index.php to /en/home, and you'll be golden.

E: Also, `DirectoryIndex` can't be a Path, AFAIK. It just tells the server which file in a directory should be served if not specified otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

`/` and `/index.php` are separate resources as far as anything accessing your site through HTTP is concerned.  Just because you are redirecting `/`, it doesn't mean anything if Google has seen links to `/index.php` before.

Just redirect `/index.php` to `/en/home` in the same way as you are redirecting `/`.